# Importing esm2015 in deno

Tags: ecmascript-6, rxjs, deno, umd, unpkg

Named import from UMD module (arent UMDs supposed to work in browsers and Deno seems similar to a browser?):

```
import { range } from "https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js";
import { operators } from "https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js";
```

results in

```
error: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js' does not provide an export named 'operators'
error: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js' does not provide an export named 'range'
```

also importing directly from ES2015

```
import { range } from "https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/esm2015/index.js";
import { filter, map } from "https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/esm2015/operators/index.js";
```

appears to be working, loads a lot of internal modules and then crashes:

```
Download https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/esm2015/internal/observable/fromEvent
/// downloads 150 internal modules
Download https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/esm2015/internal/util/Immediate.js  // 5 minutes later
error: Import 'https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/esm2015/internal/symbol/observable.js' failed: 500 Internal Server Error
    at https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/esm2015/index.js:4:0
```

RxJS seems a fairly well maintained library - I don't suppose it's incorrectly packaged, but since it does start to download internal es2015 modules I assumed the import is done correctly

---

**UPDATE**:
UMD usage remains unsolved, it's still unclear how 'dist/global/rxjs.umd.js' works

Comment: should this be split into two questions for UMD / ES2015?

Answer (score 2):

There is documented somewhere -- can't find the reference -- that unpkg breaks esm2015 packages into subpackages (esm2015/operators/index.js)

Could not find a way to import from UMD, however:

```js
// @deno-types="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.6.3/index.d.ts"

//unpkg
import { range } from "https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/esm2015/index.js";
import { filter, map } from "https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.3/dist/esm2015/operators/index.js";

// skypack or pika.dev
import { range }from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/rxjs';    // WORKS!!!
import { map, filter }from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/rxjs/operators';

// jspm
import { range } from "https://jspm.dev/npm:rxjs@6.6.3";   // WORKS!!!
import { map, filter } from "https://jspm.dev/npm:rxjs@6.6.3/operators";

// code to verify imports work properly
range(1, 200)
  .pipe(
    filter((x:number) => x % 2 === 1),
    map((x:number) => x + x)
  )
  .subscribe((x:number) => console.log(x));

/*
2
6
10
14
...
390
394
398
*/
```

Needs further looking into:

- https://cdn.esm.sh => "esm.sh will polyfill the node internal modules(fs,os,etc) with https://deno.land/std/node to support some modules to work in Deno"
- skypack.dev seems to be able to support more features than initially thought `import { range } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/pin/rxjs@v6.6.3-Hu9diWQqdrdn7RiydblX/mode=imports/optimized/rxjs.js";`